# Connection refused on bluetooth socket.connect() - android

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

First, I know this issue has been up before but none of the sugested solutions i found solves my problem...

After pairing device with

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

I try to connect using

```
boolean connected = false;
String cause = "";
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    try {
        mmSocket.connect(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("btact","fail"+i+" - "+e.getMessage());
        cause = e.getMessage();
        continue;
    }
    connected = true;
}

if(!connected){
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                " socket during connection failure", e2);
    }

    Log.e("----btact----", cause);
    connectionFailed();
    return;             
}
```

This gives me
fail0 -  Connection refused
fail1 -  File descriptor in bad state
fail2 -  File descriptor in bad state
File descriptor in bad state

Whay may cause this problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: you are getting error in connection i guess.why are you using  mmSocket.connect(); thrice using for loop.

Comment: yep. Because that's seems to be the standard way to "solve" connection problems with android bluetooth sockets. Apparently it usually works the second or third time...

Comment: Having same problem. I can connect successfully to a wireless headset when paired, but when I try to connect to my pc's bluetooth dongle, I get this same issue. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Radu, For API 10 and above we can use createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord and 
listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord, it works fine!
For API 9, I am forced to use this as methods in API dont work -
http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/bluetooth-reflection-and-legacy-nfc/